# Perl: how do I remove the last written line in an output file?

Tags: perl

I was wondering whether it is possible to remove the last line that was written in the output file with `[print OUT "blabla";]` in perl? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: As in "undo the last print command" from within Perl? Or just remove the last line of the file after Perl's finished building it?

Comment: I mean "undo last print command". Overwrite last print command would also do the trick for me.

Comment: [`seek( $fh, -12, SEEK_CUR )`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Perl, how do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388304/in-perl-how-do-i-change-delete-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file-or-append-to-the-be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will delete the last line from a file:

```
open (FH, "+< $file")               or die "can't update $file: $!";
while ( <FH> ) {
    $addr = tell(FH) unless eof(FH);
}
truncate(FH, $addr)                 or die "can't truncate $file: $!";
```

Answer (score 4):

See: [In Perl, how do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388304/in-perl-how-do-i-change-delete-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file-or-append-to-the-be)

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion:  Defer printing the line until you know that you need to print it.

Comment: I have a couple of nested foreach statements. If I defer printing the line, I will already have passed the iteration that contains the info I want.

Comment: How about a variable to store what you need?