# Getting rid of an empty line when adding new lines to a file (in Perl)

Tags: perl, fileupdate

I have files with daily stocks prices saved in text files when each line of the file represents one day data. For example:

```
20/05/2013  23.46   23.58   23.43   23.57   32884800    23.57
17/05/2013  23.27   23.48   23.2    23.46   41037700    23.46
```

I have created an updater which checks the last date in the saved file (the last date appears at at the top of the file), compares it to the current date and if not equal updates the missing data by appending the missing lines only (the new lines are added on top of the existing file).

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4388309/1119381) approach to append the lines:

```
open my $in,  '<',  $file      or die "Can't read old file: $!";
open my $out, '>', "$file.new" or die "Can't write new file: $!";

print $out "# Add this line to the top\n";

while( <$in> )
    {
    print $out $_;
    }

close $out;
```

And generally it works fine with only one problem. There is one empty line being added between the oldest line and first new added line. For example, if my last saved date was

```
15/05/2013  23.04   23.25   22.91   23.24   40153000    23.24
```

and then new line is being added:

```
16/05/2013  23.1    23.35   23.1    23.27   33023300    23.27
```

It will look like that:

```
15/05/2013  23.04   23.25   22.91   23.24   40153000    23.24

16/05/2013  23.1    23.35   23.1    23.27   33023300    23.27
```

I want it to look like that:

```
15/05/2013  23.04   23.25   22.91   23.24   40153000    23.24
16/05/2013  23.1    23.35   23.1    23.27   33023300    23.27
```

I thought to get rid of the `\n` when adding the lines but then it will produce just one long string. I guess I should somehow remove the `\n` but just for the last line. How do I do that?

**EDIT**: Line endings seem to be just `LF`, not `CRLF`. Does that matter? Because currently it seems that the line is not matching the empty line pattern like this or this: `/^\s*$/` or this: `/^$/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chomp` to intelligently eat newlines (in case of untranslated CRLF), then actually output a newline.  In between, you can skip if the line is empty:

```
while( <$in> )
{
    chomp; chomp;        # Eat up to two newlines, just in case
    next if /^\s*$/;     # Line is empty or contains whitespace
    print $out "$_\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however after changing my code as you have suggested - didn't change the file appearance. It is still showing a blank line. BTW, I believe that to check for an empty file, this regex should be used `/^\s*$/`, without `\s*`. But even after this change, the line persists.

Comment: I have just noticed that the empty line is only LF, not CRLF. Does that matter when using such regex: `/^$/`? Thanks!

Comment: That's fine.  All that is doing is matching the entire string, with optional whitespace.  There should be no CR or LF characters in the string after those chomps, that's why we explicitly write one out.  Maybe paranoid, but not a bad habit if you occasionally deal with Windows-style text files.