# Compare two files and write the lines from second file to first file

Tags: perl

I Have two files name test1 and test2. The contents of the files are as follows.

test1

```
nijin:qwe123
nijintest:qwerty
nijintest2:abcsdef
nijin2:qwehj
```

test2

```
nijin:qwe
nijintest2:abc
```

I have to change the values of `nijin` and `nijintest2` in test1 to match that in test2, leaving all other values alone.  I have tried all possible Perl replace comments without any success. Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit**

I have tried many open close file functions to replace the entry but none of them gives a required output. I have tried everything here [`In Perl, how do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388304/in-perl-how-do-i-change-delete-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file-or-append-to-the-b) . But with no luck

Comment: Where are the scripts you have tried?  Have you heard of `comm`?

Comment: @squiguy: I haven't heard of `comm`. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @Borodin [Here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) it is.  But after reading it further, doesn't look like it works in this case.

Comment: I have tried many open close file functions to replace the entry but none of them gives a required output. I have tried everything here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388304/in-perl-how-do-i-change-delete-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file-or-append-to-the-b . But with no luck

Comment: @user183393: I appreciate your efforts, but you should edit your own question to provide additional information. Please don't add comments

Comment: Please show your nearest-to-successful attempt.  At the least, it will show us what your planned algorithm is.  It isn't very hard to do, but it does require a little thinking.

Answer (score 1):

This works, though it could probably still be compressed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

die "Usage: $0 map [file ...]\n" unless scalar(@ARGV) >= 1;

my %mapping;
open my $fh, "<", $ARGV[0] or die "Failed to open $ARGV[0] for reading";
while (<$fh>)
{
    my($key, $value) = ($_ =~ m/^([^:]*):(.*)/);
    $mapping{$key} = "$value\n";
}
close $fh;

shift;

while (<>)
{
    my($key) = ($_ =~ m/^([^:]*):/);
    $_ = "$key:$mapping{$key}" if (defined $mapping{$key});
    print;
}
```

If it is called `sub.pl`, you can run:

```
perl sub.pl test2 test1
perl sub.pl test2 <test1
perl sub.pl test2 test1 test3 test4
```

For the first two invocations, the output is:

```
nijin:qwe
nijintest:qwerty
nijintest2:abc
nijin2:qwehj
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for importing any number of new files.  I also included code for appending new entries, which you didn't specify how you wanted handled.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

die "Usage: $0 dbfile [mapfiles ...]\n" if @ARGV < 2;

my $db = shift;

my %mapping = map {chomp; /([^:]*)/; $1 => $_} <>;

local @ARGV = $db;
local $^I = '.bak';
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    /([^:]*)/;
    print delete $mapping{$1} // $_, "\n";
}
#unlink "$db$^I"; # Uncomment if you want to delete backup

# Append new entries;
open my $fh, '>>', $db;
$fh->print($_, "\n") for values %mapping;
```